# Iterate through nodes in Chef

Tags: nagios, chef-recipe, chef-infra

Could someone please help me with documentations or suggestions on how I can iterate through the servers in the nodes folder.

I would like to create hosts,hostgroup files etc for nagios using this.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for all nodes:

```
nodes = search(:node, '*:*')
```

And then iterate over those results

```
nodes.each do |node|
  # do something...
end
```